# Plotly - how to format x-axis datetime to a custom format [12AM = 12a]?

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, plotly

I'm trying to change the format of my datetime x-axis ticks to be a specific custom format that matches the rest of my company's formatting.

using `fig.update_xaxes(tickformat='%-I %p')` I can get to a format that looks like this:

[12AM, 3AM, 6AM, 9AM, 12p, etc...]

But my desired output is this:

[12a, 3a, 6a, 9a, 12p, etc...]

Is there a way to do this simply using the `tickformat` options, or do I have do some sort of lambda function in addition? If so, what would that look like? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format seams not to be available according to this [list](https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/date-format-and-time-series/).
You could format it yourself using *ticktext* and a formatting function which you probably already have, source [here](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/).

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = dates_array,
        ticktext = [compute_your_format_from_date(date) for date in dates_array],
    )
)
```